# Somewhat customized "align" environment?

Tags: align

Neither of the two "versions" below gives me what I would like.  The first one is somewhat tolerable.  However, I would like the two instances of `\sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)}` to be aligned with each other, but with only as much space between the foregoing `\sum_{\text{odd } k} (-1)^{(k-1)/2}` and `\sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)}` as appears in the first version.  That's not what the second version gives me; instead it has a vast amount of horizontal white space between those two things.  How should I do this?

First version:

```
\begin{align}
\cos \sum_n \theta_n
& = \sum_{\text{even } k} (-1)^{k/2}
\sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)} \prod_{n\in A} \sin\theta_n \prod_{n\not\in A} \cos\theta_n \\
\sin \sum_n \theta_n
& = \sum_{\text{odd } k} (-1)^{(k-1)/2}
\sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)} \prod_{n\in A} \sin\theta_n \prod_{n\not\in A} \cos\theta_n
\end{align}
```

Second version

```
\begin{align}
\cos \sum_n \theta_n
& = \sum_{\text{even } k} (-1)^{k/2}
& \sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)} \prod_{n\in A} \sin\theta_n \prod_{n\not\in A} \cos\theta_n \\
\sin \sum_n \theta_n
& = \sum_{\text{odd } k} (-1)^{(k-1)/2}
& \sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)} \prod_{n\in A} \sin\theta_n \prod_{n\not\in A} \cos\theta_n
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `alignat` (and `\notin` instead of `\not\in`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\cos \sum_n \theta_n
& = \sum_{\text{even } k} (-1)^{k/2}
&&\sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)} \prod_{n\in A} \sin\theta_n \prod_{n\notin A} \cos\theta_n \\
\sin \sum_n \theta_n
& = \sum_{\text{odd } k} (-1)^{(k-1)/2}
&&\sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)} \prod_{n\in A} \sin\theta_n \prod_{n\notin A} \cos\theta_n
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I knew "alignat" exists but I've never used it before and didn't know it needed that number in braces.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that is what you want? It uses the `alignat` environment, and the `\smashoperator` command from `mathtools`:

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\cos \sum_n \theta_n
& = \smashoperator{\sum_{\text{even } k}} (-1)^{\tfrac{k}{2}}
& & \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)}} \prod_{n\in A} \sin\theta_n \prod_{n\not\in A} \cos\theta_n \\
\sin \sum_n \theta_n
& = \smashoperator{\sum_{\text{odd } k}} (-1)^{\tfrac{k-1}{2}}
& & \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{(A\,:\,|A|=k)}} \prod_{n\in A} \sin\theta_n \prod_{n\not\in A} \cos\theta_n
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1.  But this seems a bit too crowded, and I dislike using vertically stacked fractions (Is there a standard name for those?) in superscripts.

Comment: You mean the fractions in the exponent? I used `\tfrac`, which makes numerator and denominator `\scriptstyle`. I used them as a possibility, because I prefer them, but you can change that.. You also can make it a little less crowded, using simply $\lvert A\rvert=k$ as a subscript for the third sums.